# How to add column in cassandra for Bulk Loading Using Java API?

Tags: java, cassandra

i am trying to add column but its not working out
i have (Total 10 columns) three composite key and 7 columns (Except composite key)
i want to add those columns in my api to build sstable to load into cassandra using SstableLaoder

I am getting this Exception:

"Composite column is already fully constructed"

Builder builder = compositeColumn.builder();

```
 while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
          if (entry.parse(line, lineNumber))

{

       usersWriter.newRow(bytes(entry.sn));
        builder.add(bytes(entry.ts));
        builder.add(bytes(entry.dn));
 builder.add(bytes(entry.re));
//builder.add(bytes(entry.password));
        //builder.add(bytes(entry.email));

        usersWriter.addColumn(builder.add(bytes("ds")).build(),bytes(entry.ds), timestamp);
        //usersWriter.addColumn(builder.add(bytes("re")).build(),bytes(entry.re), timestamp);
//      usersWriter.addColumn(builder.add(bytes("age")).build(),bytes(entry.age), timestamp);
//      usersWriter.addColumn(builder.add(bytes("password")).build(),bytes(entry.password), timestamp);
//      usersWriter.addColumn(builder.add(bytes("email")).build(),bytes(entry.email), timestamp);
 //usersWriter.addColumn(builder.add(bytes("msgid")).build(),bytes(entry.key), timestamp);

        builder = compositeColumn.builder();
 System.out.println(lineNumber);

}
```